# Windows API DiInstallDevices causes Exception

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, pinvoke, driver

I am trying to access Win32 APIs to install a driver on a device. I am using a bunch of functions from the `setupapi.h`, all of which work well. In this piece of code, I am using those to get the parameters (i.e. names of/pointers to device and driver) that are needed to call this install function (which is not part of the `setupapi.h` but of the `newdev.h`).
Following is my P/Invoke and the actual method call. I have used the debugger to investigate and I am pretty sure that the information I get from the SetupAPI is correct. (I.e., the parameters are fine, by which I mean that they do contain the desired information.)

```cs
IntPtr deviceInfoSet;
Win32SetupApi.SP_DEVINFO_DATA devInfoData;
GetDeviceHandleFromMatch(deviceInfo, out deviceInfoSet, out devInfoData);
Win32SetupApi.SP_DRVINFO_DATA drvInfoData;
GetDriverHandleFromMatch(driverInstance, deviceInfoSet, devInfoData, out drvInfoData);

try
{
   bool needReboot = false;
   Win32SetupApi.DiInstallDevice(
      IntPtr.Zero,
      deviceInfoSet,
      devInfoData,
      drvInfoData,
      0,
      ref needReboot);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw;
}
```

```cs
[DllImport("newdev.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  public static extern bool DiInstallDevice(
     IntPtr hParent, 
     IntPtr lpInfoSet, 
     SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData,
     SP_DRVINFO_DATA DriverInfoData,
     UInt32 Flags, 
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] ref bool NeedReboot);
```

The exception I get is "Attempt to read/write protected memory", there is no information available via LastWin32Error.

Any thought on what might blow up here ist greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```cs
[DllImport("newdev.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool DiInstallDevice(
    IntPtr hParent, 
    IntPtr lpInfoSet, 
    ref SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData,
    ref SP_DRVINFO_DATA DriverInfoData,
    UInt32 Flags, 
    ref bool NeedReboot);
```

The structs have to be passed by reference as descrided [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff544710%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Not sure whether the Bool marshalling was wrong, but I removed that, too.

Can't believe this took hours to figure out again, gotta love P/Invoke. Hope this will help somebody else, too.